# Is it possible to have tuple assignment to variables in Scala?

Tags: scala, variable-assignment, tuples

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tuple parameter declaration and assignment oddity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624484/tuple-parameter-declaration-and-assignment-oddity)

In Scala, one can do multiple-variable assignment to tuples via:

```
val (a, b) = (1, 2)
```

But a similar syntax for assignment to variables doesn't appear to work. For example I'd like to do this:

```
var (c, d) = (3, 4)
(c, d) = (5, 6)
```

I'd like to reuse `c` and `d` in multiple-variable assignment. Is this possible?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This isn't simply "multiple variable assignment", it's fully-featured pattern matching!

So the following are all valid:

```
val (a, b) = (1, 2)
val Array(a, b) = Array(1, 2)
val h :: t = List(1, 2)
val List(a, Some(b)) = List(1, Option(2))
```

This is the way that pattern matching works, it'll de-construct something into smaller parts, and bind those parts to new names.  As specified, pattern matching won't bind to pre-existing references, you'd have to do this yourself.

```
var x: Int = _
var y: Int = _

val (a, b) = (1, 2)
x = a
y = b

// or

(1,2) match {
  case (a,b) => x = a; y = b
  case _ =>
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't think what you want is possible, but you can get something quite similar with the "magical" update method.

```
case class P(var x:Int, var y:Int) {
  def update(xy:(Int, Int)) {
    x = xy._1
    y = xy._2
  }
}

val p = P(1,2)
p() = (3,4)
```

Comment: omg, am I supposed to understand this? Just to make a variable assignment?

Comment: And a case class with mutable members? Is this ok?

Comment: It's perfectly valid, even though it's a bit of a code smell

Comment: i agree it's a code smell, but I don't think there is a non-smelly way to answer this ;)