# Scala: How to get access to my declared val?

Tags: scala

If I declare a val `1` how can I get access to it without changing name `val 1`?

```
val 1 = ONE
def ONE = 1

print(1) // `1` should be a reference to ONE which I declared above.
```

Answer (score 2):

This does not declare a variable with the name `1`:

```
val 1 = ONE
```

What it does instead is pattern matching - and the result is not useful.

Try this, and you'll get a pattern match error:

```
def ONE = 2
val 1 = ONE
```

Variables in Scala cannot have names that consists of only digits, or that start with a digit. You cannot declare a variable with the name `1`.

Comment: But I can write `var 1 = ONE` as well. And it's a misleading syntax.

Comment: That works the same as `val 1 = ONE` (pattern matching, not declaring a variable).

Comment: Yes, this is surprising syntax, but pattern matching when defining a `val` or `var` can be very useful, especially when used with tuples. See, for example [Is it possible to have tuple assignment to variables in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196678/is-it-possible-to-have-tuple-assignment-to-variables-in-scala)

Comment: When I use tuples I declare a variable `var (a, b) = (1, 2)`. This isn't like my case.

Comment: @barbara I know that. It was just to show what the possibilities are with pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Jesper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135589/jesper) said it's pattern matching. Consider this code which is similar to yours:

```
def ONE_AND_TWO = (1, 2)
val (1, b) = ONE_AND_TWO
println(b) // prints 2
val (2, _) = ONE_AND_TWO //scala.MatchError: (1,2) (of class scala.Tuple2$mcII$sp)
```

In your case you have just single value instead of tuple. If you however want to name variable, value or function as close to `1` as possible you can use:

```
def `1` = ONE
```