# Swapping two vars in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tuple parameter declaration and assignment oddity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624484/tuple-parameter-declaration-and-assignment-oddity)

In python I can do

```
>>> (a,b) = (1,2)
>>> (b,a) = (a,b)
>>> (a,b)
(2, 1)
```

But in scala:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.1.final (OpenJDK Server VM, Java 1.6.0_20).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> var (a,b) = (1,2)
a: Int = 1
b: Int = 2

scala> (a,b)=(b,a)
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '=' found.
       (a,b)=(b,a)
            ^
```

So while I can initialise vars as a tuple, I cannot assign them as a tuple. Any way to get around this, other than using a tmp var?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624484/tuple-parameter-declaration-and-assignment-oddity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196678/is-it-possible-to-have-tuple-assignment-to-variables-in-scala

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no simple way. The expression `(a,b)` constructs an immutable object of type `Tuple[Int, Int]`. Within this tuple, the identities of `a` and `b` as mutable `var`s are lost. Two previous questions may give a little more information:

[Tuple parameter declaration and assignment oddity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624484/tuple-parameter-declaration-and-assignment-oddity)

[Is it possible to have tuple assignment to variables in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196678/is-it-possible-to-have-tuple-assignment-to-variables-in-scala)

Answer (score 15):

This is Scala 2.9.0.1

```
scala> val pair = (1,2)
pair: (Int,Int) = (1,2)

scala> val swappedPair = pair.swap
swappedPair: (Int,Int) = (2,1)
```

The method `swap` produces another tuple instead of changing the old one and I don't know if it has been there in Scala 2.8.1.

Comment: yes, it is there in 2.8, but this only returns a swapped tuple. So the problem of swapping the ids of the vars is not solved.