# Play scala functions return multiple items multiple times

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I have a function that returns Long and a Json object which I would like to call multiple times using the same variable names.

```
def returnMultipleItems (): (Long, JsObject) = {

    val number:Long = 123

    val json = Json.obj(
        "Name" -> "Tom",
        "age" -> 42
    )

    return(number, json)
}
```

When calling the function like this it works fine.

```
var (number, json) = returnMultipleItems    
println("Number = " + number, ", Json = " + json)
```

I would like to call the function two or more times using the same variable names. With this I get error messages like ";" is expected but "=" is found.

```
var number:Long = 0
var json:JsObject = Json.obj()

(number, json) = returnMultipleItems // Call the function

(number, json) = returnMultipleItems // Call the function again
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May not be exactly what you're looking for but you could assign the variable to the tuple (instead of the contents) e.g.

```
var numJson = returnMultipleItems
println("Number = " + numJson._1, ", Json = " + numJson._2)
numJson = returnMultipleItems
println("Number = " + numJson._1, ", Json = " + numJson._2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Scala does not accept multiple variable assigment. However, your first example works because Scala interprets the form `var (x, y) = (1, 2)` as *pattern matching*.

A full explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624484/tuple-parameter-declaration-and-assignment-oddity) and workarounds are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196678/is-it-possible-to-have-tuple-assignment-to-variables-in-scala).